# Deploying MonoGame on Android

Tags: c#, android, monogame

I've developed a game using MonoGame for Android (with Xamarin). When deploying to my Android device (via the Xamarin Studio IDE) it installs 3 apps - Monogame-Android-8-support, Monogame-Shared-Runtime and the actual game.

Now I'd like to know how you can package all those into one APK in order to publish the app.

Comment: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @craftworkgames comment, there's a [xamarin  guide on publishing](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/). Essentially, the steps are:

1. Compile for release (Disable debugging and build in release mode)
2. Create a private key (This is so you can sign the APK)
3. Zipalign the APK (This is for optimizations with Android)

After this, you have to jump through various google hoops to get it on the play store, starting with creating a developer account, submitting assets like an icon, screenshots, a promo graphic (optional) and then uploading to google play if it's accepted.

The link to the guide should go into further detail if you need more guidance.